# How to find all audio files on SDCard (eclipse, android)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, search, audio

i have already this code...but i want to search also trough the sub folders instead of just searching trough sdcard.sorry for my english ;)
thanks for helping, vinzenz

```
public class SongsManager {
// SDCard Path
final String MEDIA_PATH = new String("/sdcard/");
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

// Constructor
public SongsManager(){
    **strong text**
 }

/**
 * Function to read all mp3 files from sdcard
 * and store the details in ArrayList
 * */
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList(){
    File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);

    if (home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter()).length > 0) {
        for (File file : home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter())) {
            HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
            song.put("songTitle", file.getName().substring(0, (file.getName().length() - 4)));
            song.put("songPath", file.getPath());

            // Adding each song to SongList
            songsList.add(song);
        }
    }
    // return songs list array
    return songsList;
}
```

}

Answer (score 5):

This code might help you. It searches for songs in SD card (even in subfolders) & stores the details in `songsList`.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    String[] STAR = { "*" };

    Cursor cursor;
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";


    cursor = managedQuery(uri, STAR, selection, null, null);

    if (cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String songName = cursor
                        .getString(cursor
                                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));


                String path = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));


                String albumName = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));
                int albumId = cursor
                        .getInt(cursor
                                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID));

                HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
                song.put("songTitle",albumName+" "+songName+"___"+albumId);
                song.put("songPath",path );
                songsList.add(song);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());


        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for a nice answer, altho the method managedQuery is deprecated, could you update this answer please?

Comment: Instead of managedQuery() which is deprecated, one can use getContentResolver().query() with the same parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Considering that Media is scanned from sdcard, you can get this information from MediaStore

```
 musiccursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            proj, MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE  + "= audio/mpeg", null, null);

int column_index = musiccursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);


while(musiccursor.moveToNext()){

String path = musiccursor.get(column_index);
//path is your music path, use this
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no direct solution to your question
you have to write a piece of code to iterate through each files in a directory, if current file is a directory then list all files of that directory and iterate again on all file of it and so on. 
Something like below code will help as in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008043/list-all-files-from-directories-and-subdirectories-in-java/3008198)

```
import java.io.File;

public class DirectoryReader {

  static int spc_count=-1;

  static void process(File aFile) {
    spc_count++;

    if(aFile.isFile()) {
      // your logic to check songs file
    } else if (aFile.isDirectory()) {

      File[] listOfFiles = aFile.listFiles();
      if(listOfFiles!=null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
          process(listOfFiles[i]);
        }
      } else {
        // access is denied
      }
    }

    spc_count--;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String nam = "/sdcard/";
    File aFile = new File(nam);
    process(aFile);
  }

}
```