# Simple MP3 player for Android - always crash - code is here

Tags: java, android

```
package com.example.hhh.Test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;  
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.List;
import android.app.ListActivity;  
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.view.View; 
import android.widget.AdapterView; 
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView; 

class Mp3Filter implements FilenameFilter {
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return (name.endsWith(".mp3"));
    } 
}

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    String SD_PATH = new String("/sdcard/");
    List<String> songs = new ArrayList<String>();
     MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    ListView list;
    File home = new File(SD_PATH);
     ArrayAdapter<String> songList;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        updateSongList();

             list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
             list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                     try {
                         mp.reset();
                         mp.setDataSource(SD_PATH + songs.get(position));
                         mp.prepare();
                         mp.start();
                     }
                     catch (IOException e) {
                         e.printStackTrace();
                     }

                 }
             });
         }


     private void updateSongList() {
         File home = new File(SD_PATH);
         if (home.listFiles(new Mp3Filter()).length > 0) {
             for (File file : home.listFiles(new Mp3Filter())) {
                 songs.add(file.getName());
             }
             songList = (ArrayAdapter<String>) songs;
             setListAdapter(songList);

         }
    } 
}
```

Comment: "always crash" ..; so, where's the stacktrace? Could you please post your code in a decent code-form, not half quote, half code?

Comment: at first set `ListView list = getListView();` Remove `list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);`

Comment: its dose not reach to the stacktrace at all its not open in the mobile at all but at the android studio its give me no error

Comment: If you are not getting an error then how do you know it is crashing?

Comment: at the android monitor its written in it

Answer (score 0):

To fetch song avoid giving path like `/sdcard/`. this way it wont fetch each & every songs from internal directory.

Use content provider to fetch list of songs & issue may came because path is not proper in your case

Try below code it worked for me.

```
    public class SongActivity extends Activity {
        private MediaPlayer mp;
        private ListView list;
        private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.home_screen_slider);
            mp = new MediaPlayer();
            updateSongList();// Use of AsynTask is preferable
            list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
            list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    try {
                        if (mp != null) {
                            mp.reset();
                            mp.setDataSource(songsList.get(position).get("songPath"));
                            mp.prepare();
                            mp.start();
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });
            list.setAdapter(new SongAdapter(this.songsList));
            findViewById(R.id.btnStop).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying())
                        mp.stop();
                }
            });
        }


        private void updateSongList() {
            songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            String[] STAR = {"*"};
            Cursor cursor;
            Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";
            cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, STAR, selection, null, null);
            if (cursor != null) {
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        String songName = cursor
                                .getString(cursor
                                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
                        String path = cursor.getString(cursor
                                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
                        String albumName = cursor.getString(cursor
                                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));
                        int albumId = cursor
                                .getInt(cursor
                                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID));
                        HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        song.put("songTitle", albumName + " " + songName + "___" + albumId);
                        song.put("songPath", path);
                        songsList.add(song);
                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }
            }

        }

        private class SongAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
            public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listSongs;
            int size = 0;

            public SongAdapter(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listSongs) {
                this.listSongs = listSongs;
                if (listSongs != null && !listSongs.isEmpty())
                    size = listSongs.size();
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return size;
            }

            @Override
            public HashMap<String, String> getItem(int position) {
                return this.listSongs.get(position);
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return position;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                // Here you can use ViewHolder for View Resuability
//https://stackoverflow.com/a/34349311/1140237
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(SongActivity.this).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
                TextView txt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                HashMap<String, String> song = this.listSongs.get(position);
                txt.setText(song.get("songTitle"));
                return convertView;
            }
        }
    }
```

*Layout*

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relative_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffc699">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnStop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Stop" />


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/btnSelect"></ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

*To get song list i used answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/19480973*

Answer (score -1):

use following code

```
package com.materialexample;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Mp3Filter implements FilenameFilter {
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return (name.endsWith(".mp3"));
    }
}

public class PlayerActivity extends ListActivity {

    String SD_PATH = new String("/sdcard/");
    List<String> songs = new ArrayList<String>();
    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    ListView listViewssss;
    File home = new File(SD_PATH);
    ArrayAdapter<String> songList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        /*setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);*/
        listViewssss = getListView();
        updateSongList();
        listViewssss.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                try {
                    mp.reset();
                    mp.setDataSource(SD_PATH + songs.get(position));
                    mp.prepare();
                    mp.start();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    private void updateSongList() {
        File home = new File(SD_PATH);
        if (home.listFiles(new Mp3Filter()).length > 0) {
            for (File file : home.listFiles(new Mp3Filter())) {
                songs.add(file.getName());
            }

            songList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, songs);
            setListAdapter(songList);
        }
    }
}
```

don't miss to change your Activity name.

Comment: You need to explain what you have done here. This is merely doing someones work for them. Edit your question with an explanation to assist future viewers as well.

Comment: still its just blink in the mobile screen and nothing appear

Comment: i am nothing done more remove setContentView(R.layout.activity_player); becuse they have extends ListActivity, and also replace  list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView); with  listViewssss = getListView(); and also replace songList = (ArrayAdapter<String>) songs; with songList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, songs); because error in casting arraylist with ArrayAdapter.