# How to get a list of all audio files using android.database.Cursor?

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider, android-cursor, android-cursorloader

I came across [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19480778/how-to-find-all-audio-files-on-sdcard-eclipse-android) of this problem through [`Cursor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html),

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    void example() {

        List<File> localAudioFiles = new LinkedList<>();

        Uri contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

        // The problem is that it contains a list of files as of the moment
        // when the operating system has been rebooted.
        try (Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                contentUri,
                projection,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0",
                null,
                null);) {

            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                String audio = cursor.getString(column_index);    
                localAudioFiles.add(new File(audio));
            }

        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        }
    }
}
```

but as far as I understand, its state needs to be updated compulsorily, because files added through the AVD file manager are not detected in this way until the device is rebooted.

- How can I forcefully update the state of the entity [`Cursor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html)?
- Is the solution worth it, or is it not better than recursively traversing all the directories?

Comment: `I came across the solution of this problem` ? Which problem?

Comment: Problem: "get a list of all audio files [in the Android device file system]".

Comment: Problem? I do not see that as a problem but as a task you want to fullfill.

Comment: The question of how to solve this problem is through the use of the Cursor object.
Because: "files added through the AVD file manager are not detected in this way until the device is rebooted".

Comment: You have not yet described a problem you encountered doing so. Nor dont we know what you tried. If you want help you should post a to the point problem.