# Ubuntu - How to run a command on folder and its subdirectories , and create a file in each folder with the output?

Tags: java, shell, ubuntu, terminal, directory

I have a directory `myDir` with a lot of subdirectories .

I want to execute the following command :

```
java -cp bin Main
```

on each and every subdirectory , and then , create (in each subdirectory) a file with the output of the command `java -cp bin Main` on the subdirectory .

I tried this :

```
// edited , doesn't work
```

But it doesn't really work

Any idea how to do that ?

Thanks

Comment: `find . -type d` will give you all the directories. I would recommend that you do this _in_ Java - it will be easier.

Comment: Downvoter , I have no idea why you downvoted my post , but feel free to downvote as much as you want ...I think it's an excellent question !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution:

```
find /home/a/Desktop/myfolder -type d -exec sh -c '(cd {} && YOUR-COMMAND-GOES-HERE)' ';'
```

Instead of `YOUR-COMMAND-GOES-HERE` you can put for example `java -cp bin Main`

So :

```
find /home/a/Desktop/myfolder -type d -exec sh -c '(cd {} && java -cp bin Main)' ';'
```

Answer (score 0):

`$i` will have the full path (relative to `$base`). Try instead `iterator "$dir/$(basename $i)"` or just `iterator "$i"`.

Your script also doesn't do what you say, I suspect you want to run `java -cp bin Main` inside the `if`, not on the `else` (which runs if the file is *not* a directory).

Answer (score 0):

Either make your java program run itself on all subfolders: [list all files from directories and subdirectories in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008043/list-all-files-from-directories-and-subdirectories-in-java)

Or pass all folders that you want your java program to create the output into your java program. Something like:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        if (args != null && args.length>0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
            {
                System.out.println("Create a file in the folder "+args[i]);
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("args were not provided");
        }
    }
}
```

And execute it using

java -cp $YOURCLASSPATH Test `find . -type d`